# Regex challenge, Custom Chess Notation

Tags: regex, expression, notation

```
Place a piece on the board (ex: Qld1 – place the white queen on D1, Kde8 – place the black king on E8).  Piece abbreviations are:
K = king
Q = queen
B = bishop
N = knight
R = rook
P = pawn
and l = light, d = dark.

Move a single piece on the board (ex: d8 h4 – moves the piece at D8 to the square at H4, c4 d6* - moves the piece at C4 to D6 and captures the piece at D6).
Move two pieces in a single turn (ex: e1 g1 h1 f1 – moves the king from E1 to G1 and moves the rook from H1 to F1.  This is called a “king-side castle”).
```

I need help writing a single regex to take all options listed. I got this far:

```
([KQNBR]?([a-h]?[1-8]?x)?[a-h]([2-7]|[18](=[KQNBR])?)|0-0(-0)?)(\(ep\)|\+{1,2})?
```

or

`([BKNPQR]?)([a-h]?)([0-9]?)([x=]?)([BKNPQR\*]|[a-h][1-8])([+#]?)`

before it was decided that the chess board will take on a very different custom notation for handling moves.

The question is I need help to creating a regex expression that will validate these chess moves.

An example is that, this program will not be live manipulation of a chess board. But instead a file will be read from a stream line by line, the console application of your chess game should read each line and produce the following results for each of the moves.

The first few lines of the file should read placements of each piece Qld1 which places a white queen on D1, kde8 places the black king on E8.

Afterwards the file will read each movement, d8 h4 will move the piece in position of d8 to h4.

The single regular expression will validate the text file to read if it is a valid move based on its expression. If it is invalid, skip the move and continue.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: I think: "will you help me write a single regex to take all options listed".

Comment: Could you please provide a regex solution to a similar question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25018/tell-me-the-moves

Comment: I've updated some information. It will all be read from a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general strategy for creating complex regular expressions, you can create different regular expressions for each of the individual components.

E.g. first create a regular expression matching placement `([KQNBR][ld][a-h][1-8])`. This is easy to read and easy to create.

Then create a regular expression for the normal moves `([a-h][1-8]\s[a-h][1-8])` and then one for the castling moves (left as an exercise for the reader). These you can combine using `([KQNBR][ld][a-h][1-8])|([a-h][1-8]\s[a-h][1-8]\*?)|etc`.

You can even reuse parts of the regular expressions, e.g. call `[a-h][1-8]` `field` in your language of choice and reuse that. A move would then be something like `field + '\s' + field + '\*?'`.

Although this may not be the shortest regular expression (or the most efficient one) it will be much easier to create it and much more readable.

Comment: Very interesting, how about validating for a piece capturing? c4 d6*

Comment: I have updated the regex for move to include the optional star.

Comment: http://puu.sh/8MrHN.png What about placements such as qld6 for placing a Queen Light D6 (position) or qda4 (Queen Dark A4)

Comment: You mean to allow lowercase letters? Either use '[KQNBRkqnbr]' or use some case insensitive flag.

Comment: Oh yeah I fixed it. Thank you. It helps with other notations as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have created the following regular expression for converting copied chess24.com games into [PGN-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) games:

```
\s*(\d{1,3})\.?\s*((?:(?:O-O(?:-O)?)|(?:[KQNBR][1-8a-h]?x?[a-h]x?[1-8])|(?:[a-h]x?[a-h]?[1-8]\=?[QRNB]?))\+?)(?:\s*\d+\.?\d+?m?s)?\.?\s*((?:(?:O-O(?:-O)?)|(?:[KQNBR][1-8a-h]?x?[a-h]x?[1-8])|(?:[a-h]x?[a-h]?[1-8]\=?[QRNB]?))\+?)?(?:\s*\d+\.?\d+?m?s)?
```

with the replacement field being

```
\1. \2 \3\n
```

Or

```
$1. $2 $3\n
```

depending on your regex environment or regex engine.

Verbose regex in Python:

```python
chess_pattern = re.compile(r"""
\s*                                     # Whitespace
(\d{1,3})                               # Capture group 1: Move number between 1 and 999 will precede white side's move.
\.?                                     # Literal period, in case move numbers followed by a period. The replace pattern will restore period, so it is not captured. 
\s*                                     # Whitespace
(                                       # Capture group 2: This will collect the white side's move
(?:                                     # Start non-capturing group A: Use vertical bar | between non-capturing groups to check for castling, piece moves/captures, pawn moves/captures/promotion
(?:O-O(?:-O)?)                          # Non-capturing subgroup A1: For castling kingside or queenside. Change the O to 0 to work for sites that 0-0 for castling notation
|(?:[KQNBR][1-8a-h]?x?[a-h]x?[1-8])     # Non-capturing subgroup A2: For piece (non-pawn) moves and piece captures
|(?:[a-h]x?[a-h]?[1-8]\=?[QRNB]?)       # Non-capturing subgroup A3: Pawn moves, captures, and promotions
)                                       # End non-capturing group A
\+?                                     # Allow plus symbol for checks (attacks on king)
)                                       # End capturing group 2: White side's move
(?:\s*\d+\.?\d+?m?s)?                   # Non-capturing group B: Skip over move-times; it is possible to retain move times if you make this a capturing group
\.?                                     # Allow period in case a time ends in a decimal point
\s*                                     # Whitespace
(                                       # Capture group 3: This will collect the black side's move
(?:                                     # Start non-capturing group C: Use vertical bar | between non-capturing groups to check for castling, piece moves/captures, pawn moves/captures/promotion
(?:O-O(?:-O)?)                          # Non-capturing subgroup C1: For castling kingside or queenside. Change the O to 0 to work for sites that 0-0 for castling notation
|(?:[KQNBR][1-8a-h]?x?[a-h]x?[1-8])     # Non-capturing subgroup C2: For piece (non-pawn) moves and piece captures
|(?:[a-h]x?[a-h]?[1-8]\=?[QRNB]?)       # Non-capturing subgroup C3: Pawn moves, captures, and promotions
)                                       # End non-capturing group C
\+?                                     # Allow plus symbol for checks (attacks on king)
)?                                      # End capturing group 3: Black side's move. Question mark allows final move to be white side's move without any subsequent black moves
(?:\s*\d+\.?\d+?m?s)?                   # Non-capturing group D: Skip over move-times; it is possible to retain move times if you make this a capturing group
""",re.VERBOSE)
# Paste the entire chess game inside the raw string below where there is currently ...
chess_game = """ 
...
"""
print( pattern.sub(r'\1. \2 \3 '+'\n',chess_game) ) # Will output PGN to console
# The following writes the PGN to a file `game.pgn` in the working directory
output_PGN = open('game.pgn','w+')
output_PGN.write(pattern.sub(r'\1. \2 \3 '+'\n',chess_game))
output_PGN.close()
```

See here for an example of this in action: [regexr.com/58ngb](https://regexr.com/58ngb)

I have also implemented the above as a [Clipboard Fusion](https://www.clipboardfusion.com/) (C#) macro here: https://www.clipboardfusion.com/Macros/View/?ID=d220984d-faa4-4ba2-ab86-f16dceb42036

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex:

```
([BKNPQR][ld][a-h][1-8])|((?:(?:[a-h][1-8]\s*){2})+)
```

The first part is set-command: `([BKNPQR][ld][a-h][1-8])`

And the second part is the move-Command. As it can contain 1 or more moves at once, I needed to use the `+` operator.

One move is represented by this statement: `(?:[a-h][1-8]\s*){2}`

The `?:` is just some minor performance-improvement. It means, that the `()`-brackets won't be put into a match.

I tested it here, and it seems to work: http://regex101.com/

**Notice:** There're different kinds of regular expressions, which are all similar, but not identical. My regex is for JavaScript, but as it uses only the basic regex-rules, it should also work in any other language.